# Apply parent to children that don't have it

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I have a list of elements in a container. The elements are li which contain an a tag.

My problem is that not all of the a are inside a li tag (this is due to a previous jquery operation).

How can I iterate through the list and put the a tags that are not in a li, inside one?

Here is the html concerned:

```
<ul class="dropdownmenu" style="display: none; ">

<li><a href="Advanced">Advanced</a></li>
<li><a href="Account">Account</a></li>

<a href="Credit Notes">Credit Notes</a>
<a href="Invoices In">Invoices In</a>

<li><a href="Invoices Out">Invoices Out</a></li>
<li><a href="Invoices Jobs">Invoices Jobs</a></li>

</ul>
```

And my javascript:

```
$('li[id^="nav"]').each(function(){ // For each nav item that has fallen out of the menu due to low res etc...
    pos = $(this).position() ;
    if(pos.top > 0)
    {
        var cnt = $('ul.dropdownmenu', this).contents()
        $('ul.dropdownmenu', this).replaceWith(cnt);
        $('span.droptop', this).remove();
        $('a:has(i span)', this).remove() ;
        $('i', this).remove() ;
        // NOW WRAP As in LIs THAT DON'T HAVE ONE
        movables += $(this).html() ;
        $(this).hide() ;
        somethingHidden = true ;
    }
})
```

Comment: You cannot have any element inside a `<ul>` that is not an `<li>`. Wrap your anchors in a list item in your first operation.

Comment: You should fix whatever "previous jquery operation" is causing some of the `<li>`s to be removed.

Comment: Having an anchor directly inside unordered list element isn't valid. Fix this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap all `a` elements **before** running your function:

```
$('ul.dropdownmenu > a').wrap('<li />');
```

Comment: But won't that make the As that are already wrapped with LI doubled wrapped? i.e. <li><li><a></a></li></li>

Comment: No, because of the `>` selector. Only `a`s who are direct child of `ul` will be targeted. Check it live: http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/bMPyy/

Comment: Thanks, I just had to adjust it a bit to work with what I had:
    $('> a', this).wrap('<li />');
because it's already in a loop further up.